# Java: Storing extended objects in arraylist and calling parent toString method

Tags: java, class, arraylist, tostring

I have a question about calling toString method, wich i have declared in parent class, on extended objects saved in arrayList. I have parent "Product" class, then i have extended class "Smartphone".

My problem is that I have declared toString() method in parent class and in extended class and I need to call both methods, but i don't know how to call parent toString() method on extended objects stored in arrayList.
Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `super` to reference your parent class.

```
class A {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A's toString()";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " " + "B's toString()";
    }
}

B b = new B();
System.out.println(b); // prints "A's toString() B's toString()"
```

---

Edit:

If your child's `toString()` *always* calls the parent's, then you don't even need the `toString()` in the child.

If you want to keep a custom `toString()` for your child that is different than the parent's in some case, but you also want to be able to call the parent's `toString()` from the child, make a delegation method.

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ...
    }

    public String parentsToString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}

B b = new B();
b.parentsToString(); // will return the output of A's toString()
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have child objects stored in arrayList and i want to call parent's toString() method on these objects in arrayList. So I don't know how to call super.toString on objects in arrayList

Comment: Thak you very much for advice.

Comment: Anytime my friend. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

by default each object reference  we write ,it internally calls its own `toString` method.

if its not defined then it will call its immediate parent's `toString()` method.

but if you want to call parent's `toString()` method using child reference variable then

define `toString` in child and call parent's `toString` and append its own definition.

example

```
class Parent {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parent";
    }
}

class Child {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " " + "child";
    }
}

Child child = new Child();
System.out.println(child); // prints parent child
```